# What is vue.api.init, vue.api.call?

Tags: vue.js

I have seen the syntax "vue.api.init ()" and "vue.api.call ()", but I do not know what it is. If you have useful information or links, please let me know.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this syntax? This is function call. Where did you see it? It's unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: @estus I can not find the guide documentation for that feature. I am analyzing a product source and can not analyze it because I do not know what it is.

Comment: `vue.api` is not a conventional thing and is specific to the app. It's impossible to say anything without seeing the source you're analyzing.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask